# ArcMap avoid labels overlap themselves without removing any label

Tags: arcmap, labeling, overlapping-features

How can I avoid overlapping the labels from the same layer?

I tried using "Feature Weight", and didn't work.

Also tried "Never Remove (place overlapping)" which works, but I need to show all the labels.

How can I achieve this without converting the labels to annotations and moving them manually?

[image]

Comment: Hello @KadirŞahbaz with all due respect, could you please have a brief explanation why remove the thanks?

Comment: Hello @Papu. Of course. Could you please read this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/398935)?

Comment: GIS SE is a collaborative database compilation effort (questions and answers). We have a strong "no chit-chat" policy, so greetings and thanks are always removed. If you insist on adding them back, you can expect downvotes and closure. As a new user, please take the [Tour].